# Estimating degree and leading term of Hilbert-Samuel polynomial for a special case

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> (Fulton) 3.15. (a) Let $\mathscr{O} = \mathscr{O}_P(\Bbb A^2)$ for some $P \in \Bbb A^2$, $m = \mathscr{m}_P(\Bbb A^2 )$. Calculate $χ(n) = \dim_k (\mathscr{O}/m^n)$.
>   (b) Let $\mathscr{O} = \mathscr{O}_P(\Bbb A^r(k))$. Show that $χ(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $r$ in $n$, with leading coefficient $1/r !$

My attempt :

(a) Without loss of generality I just compute at $P=(0,0)$

$\mathscr{O}=k[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}$ and $m=(X,Y)\mathscr{O}$.

Then I find, $\mathscr{O}/m \cong k$, $\mathscr{O}/m^2 \cong k \oplus kx \oplus ky$, $\mathscr{O}/m^3 \cong k \oplus kx \oplus ky \oplus kx^2 \oplus kxy \oplus ky^2$ and hence by induction, $$\mathscr{O}/m^{n+1}=\mathscr{O}/m^n \oplus kx^n \oplus kx^{n-1}y \oplus \dots \oplus ky^n$$ and thus $$χ(n)=\dim_k(\mathscr{O}/m^n)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$$

(b) Proceeding similarly, $\mathscr{O}=k[X_1,\dots X_r]_{(X_1,\dots,X_r)}$ and $m=(X_1,\dots,X_r)\mathscr{O}$ , I obtained $$\mathscr{O}/m^{n+1}=\mathscr{O}/m^n \oplus kx_1^n \oplus kx_1^{n-1}x_2 \oplus \dots \oplus kx_r^n$$ and now since for any $n \in \Bbb N$, $\sum_{i=1}^r t_i=n$ has $n+r-1 \choose r-1$ many non-negative roots, I get that $$\chi(n)=\dim_k(\mathscr{O}/m^n)= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} {j+r-1 \choose r-1}$$ which unfortunately seems to be a polynomial of degree $r-1$ and also has leading coefficient $1/(r-1)!$.

> Where am I making the mistake? Can you kindly point it out? Also, is my answer for part (a) correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is correct up to your conclusion that $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} {j+r-1 \choose r-1}$ is a polynomial of degree $r-1$ with leading coefficient $\frac{1}{(r-1)!}$. You should compare this result to the work you've already done. Full solution under the spoiler text below:

> By the [Hockeystick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity), this expression is equal to $\binom{n+r-1}{r}$, which is indeed of the desired form.